# Not able to use SecureString under System.Security namespace

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to create a property of type SecureString in my viewmodel to bind it with my PasswordBox, but it looks like UWP does not support it. Am I missing something?

Comment: The usefulness of SecureString ended about 10 years ago, there are just not many practical scenarios left where you have to interop with legacy unmanaged code that requires a password.  Most certainly not in a UWP app, no point in porting it.  Code is never secure when it hasn't been subjected to a security review first, you have to start there first.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Security` does not contain `SecureString` [System.Security namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185488.aspx)

This question was already asked see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647296/windows-runtime-component-system-security-cryptography)

> If you just want to encrypt the value, there are options with the Windows.Security.Cryptography namespace, but the plaintext would still be available in the memory space of the app (eg, by having it exist in the page file or a crash dump).

Comment: Thanks for the link, In this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) Version Information at the bottom of the page contains UWP. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://gist.github.com/lindexi/e4809b4b54a36db6aa166524c89fcebb and make it to a file .

And set the PasswordBox `view:PasswordBoxHelper.Attach="True" view:PasswordBoxHelper.Password="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}"`.The Password is property that define in ViewModel.